# Xamarin iOS and Android projects no longer compile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

This is for Xamarin 8.10.11 (Build 8) for MacOS, Community Edition.

I recently returned to Xamarin development and opened a mobile project that I had worked on about a month ago.  However both the Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects have a yellow warning triangle beside them saying that the appropriate tool chain is not installed.

[image: Shows error bars]

Both are installed.

If I download the latest DMG and request to install, it says there's nothing to be done (and indicates that both iOS and Android components are already installed).

Any thoughts on what else I can try?

The Show Details in the About dialog is missing all the relevant components (a colleague sent me their listing from a correctly working installation).

Comment: check Preferences --> SDK Locations

Comment: @Jason That says the right thing.

Comment: your best bet might be to go scorched earth and delete everything and then reinstall

Comment: @Jason Started doing that, but figured it out. See my answer. Thanks for your interest! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, eventually I figured it out.

The problem is that mobile development in Visual Studio is added as an extension.  And for no reason I can fathom, all the `Mobile Development` extensions had been disabled.

[image: Showing disabled extensions.]

I have no idea how that happened, but re-enabling them made the problem go away.